# SWIFT: try to use delegate method of objective c class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, augmented-reality

I have an existing `Objective-C SDK (AugmentedKit SDK)`. I am trying to use it with `Swift`. `AugmentedKit SDK` has a class called '`AKSurfaceView`' that implements a delegate to '`AKViewDataSource`' protocol.

```
@class AKSurfaceView;
@protocol AKViewDataSource;

@protocol AKViewDelegate<AKViewDataSource>
```

AKViewDataSource looks like this:

```
@protocol AKViewDataSource<NSObject>
@required
-(AKMarkerTemplate*) viewforMarker:(AKMarker*) marker;
```

I've created a briging file, implemented other methods from `AKSurfaceView`, etc. - everything works fine but when I try to add a reference of the `AKViewDelegate` to my `UIViewControllerClass` it ends in a compile error:

"Type `POIViewController` does not conform to protocol '`AKViewDataSource`'"

My implementation looks like this:

```
class POIViewController: UIViewController, AKViewDelegate {
```

My implementation of '`viewforMarker`' in SWIFT looks like this:

```
func viewforMarker(marker:AKMarker) -> AKMarkerTemplate{
    var markerView:SimpleMarker = SimpleMarker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 230, 80))
    markerView.title.text = marker.markerName
    return markerView
}
```

Could please anybody help my to figure out how I have to implement '`viewforMarker`' so the delegate recognise it?

Comment: Is SimpleMarker an AKMarkerTemplate?

Comment: Yes, SimpleMarker is an AKMarkerTemplate

Comment: I tried your code and it compiles fine (making allowances for all the stuff one has to make allowances for).

Comment: What I suggest you do is what I did - make a simple project consisting of _just_ those declarations. You will see that it compiles just fine. Now you can figure out what's wrong in your real project.

Comment: Often you need to quality your returned objects as optionals, since its perfectly legal now for an ObjC routine to return nil. For instance: func viewforMarker(marker:AKMarker!) -> AKMarkerTemplate! (note the '!'s)

Comment: Are the delegate and data source interfaces defined in the same header? Do you have a reference to the header in your bridging file?

Comment: To quality does not solve the error...

Comment: @MikeTaverne this is my bridging-file, both header classes are included....

#ifndef Hotspot_Hotspot_Bridging_Header_h
#define Hotspot_Hotspot_Bridging_Header_h

#import "AugmentedKit/AugmentedKit.h"
#import "AugmentedKit/AKViewDataSource.h"
#import "AugmentedKit/AKViewDelegate.h"

#endif

Comment: this would be the reference to the SDK:

http://augmentedkit.com/docs/Protocols/AKViewDataSource.html#//api/name/viewforMarker:

Comment: I guess I am used to seeing import statements in the bridging header.

Comment: Did you try qualifying using ? instead of !

Comment: @MikeTaverne: Yes, I tried both

Comment: Do you need to add AKViewDataSource to your list of implemented protocols in your POIViewController declaration?

Comment: Thanks to everybody!

The solution was to put the "viewforMarker" Methode to the top of my POIViewController class...

After doing that the project compiled well!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `AKViewDelegate` is a subclass of `AKViewDataSource`, in this case, you will have to conform to `AKViewDelegate` AND `AKViewDataSource`, that means you will have to implement the required methods of both protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported your Obective-C class inside `Bridging-Header.h`, and added the following in your swift class:

```
markerView.delegate = self
```